# Power digit sum

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this excercise:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=16

The code is pretty self-explanatory: I calculate 2^n in power(n), and in sum(n), I cut off the last digit of the number. I do this as long as pow > 0. I receive the right solution for 2^15, but for one reason or another, the same code doesn't work for 2^1000. I receive 1889, which is apparently wrong.

```
def power(n):
    power = 2
    for x in range(1, n):
        power = 2*power
    return power

def sum(n):
    pow = power(n)
    sum = 0
    while pow > 0:
        modulo = pow%10
        sum = sum + modulo
        pow = int((pow - modulo)/10)
    return sum

def main():
    print(int(sum(1000)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And what would be the right result of `2^1000`?

Comment: I don't know. projecteuler just tells me that my solution is wrong.

Comment: In what way is it not working?  (Error, getting the wrong answer etc.)  Also, you have a variable `sum` in a function `sum`.  That's going to cause problems.  If I was doing this, I'd just split up the string representation of `2**1000` into the digits, cast them to `int`s then use the built in `sum` to add them up

Comment: I don't receive an integer-overflow. I receive 1889 as a solution.

Comment: `2^1000` is a *ridiculously huge* number. Anyway, the challenge here is to do it in a different way.

Comment: @alfasin no - Python uses bigint's whose limit is basically your system memory...

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is, but Python calculates it pretty quickly.

Comment: As I said, the point of the challenge is to think how to do it in a smart way.

Comment: I take it you're trying to avoid the whole converting it to a string (and just doing `sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))` as that'd be quite a large string...

Comment: You might be interested in python's power operator: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

Comment: I receive the same result without converting anything, by the way.

Comment: @TomDalton: Thanks, I could use it in the future!

Comment: Mind you... having said that: `%timeit sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))` seems fairly quick... 61 µs ± 3.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Comment: Weird.  Cutting and pasting your code, I get 1366 every time.  Not 1889.

Comment: I'm using PyScripter, maybe it handles it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple change in your code will give you the correct answer,

```
def power(n):
    power = 2
    for x in range(1, n):
        power = 2*power
    return power

def sum(n):
    pow = power(n)
    sum = 0
    while pow > 0:
        modulo = pow%10
        sum = sum + modulo
        pow = pow//10 # modified line
    return sum

def main():
    print(int(sum(1000)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The reason why your example doesn't work is because you are casting the result of a float operation to int. Floats are never precise and when they are very large, they loose precision. Hence if you convert them back to integer, you get a much lower value.

A better function using divmod() is,

```
def sum(n):
    pow = power(n)
    sum = 0
    while pow > 0:
        pow,modulo = divmod(pow,10)
        sum = sum + modulo
    return sum
```

Comment: I receive 1366 now, which is the correct answer. Weird. Didn't think that it would make that much of a difference, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your original solution **would have worked in Python 2** because [Python 2 and Python 3 handle division differently](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#integer-division).

For example `print(1/2)` gives `0` in Python2, and `0.5` in Python3. In Python3, we use `//` for floor division (which is what you want here).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for any number >= 57

The problem here is very easy to solve.

In python 3 and higher, `/` is a division that returns a float, while `//` is an integer division that always returns an integer. Since you are using float division, you are  encountering the issues with floating point arithmetic. 
[More about the issues and limitations.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

To solve your problem, change the line

`pow = int(pow - modulo)/10`

into

`pow = int(pow - modulo)//10`

or even better, you can just say `pow//=10`

Isn't python beatiful?

Answer (score 0):

```
def Power_digit_sum(n):
    number = list(str(2**n)) # pow number and convert number  in string and  list 
    result= [int(i) for i in number]# convert number in int and 
    return sum(result) # sum list
            
        
        
 print(Power_digit_sum(15)) # result 26
 print(Power_digit_sum(1000)) # result 1366
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I admit that one of my mistakes was that I forgot the comments